# Creating string table .net C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, undefined

Could you please advise me how to make an "undefined" `string[]`? For example
I'm using a basic loop:

```
string[] array = new array[100];
for (int i=amount; i >= 0; i--)
{
array[i] = textdata.ToString();
}
```

How can I write instead of `string[] array = new array[100];` something undefined that it will customize itself for the loop purposes if its going to be more than 100, making it 999999 "just in case" is a kind of stupid solution of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> list= new List<string>();

for (int i=amount; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.add(textdata.ToString());
}

string[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Why would you use a list if the size of the array is already specified by the variable "amount"?

Comment: @Lennart im guessing that the real question is just sudo code and as such so is mine, but see your point. Im guessing the real scenario actually has the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a list if you know the size of the array already?

I think it's not efficient to use 2 separate variables to fill an array. If one doesn't know the size of a collection before filling the collection, a list is good practice but obviously the variable **amount** present in the question's code tells you how big the string array should be.

```
string[] array = new string[amount+1];
for (int i=amount; i >= 0; i--)
{
    array[i] = textdata.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to use ArrayList instead of Array.

```
ArrayList<string> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=amount; i >= 0; i--) {
    arrayList.add(textdata.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is obsolete/deprecated and should not be used in _any_ circumstance. Use `List<T>` instead.